# Creating Links inside of Wordpress properly?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to create wordpress links using direct links inside of the same wordpress site, say for example...

I would have a `<a href="/catagory" >Catagory</a>`

I noticed that sometimes, the links might stack on top of eachother on the urlbar when I click on the links from a different page?

say for example it would click on another link then it would turn out to be something like

> "www.myWordpressSite.com/catagory/catagory"

Whats the proper way of doing this? Would it be something like `<a href=" get home url / link ? "></a>`

Answer (score 1):

The first `/category` is what's called a "category base". You can edit it in Settings, Permalinks page.

The second `/category` is your cateogry

There are plugin to completely get rid of the category base, search WordPress plugins for "no category base" (that's how the plugin is called, nice, huh?)

**EDIT:**

Um... now I'm not sure I understand the question now after an edit, but if URLs "stack" then you should make sure that they wither start with a `/` or with a `http://` (or `https://`)